# Alternating link destination

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am just starting programming, and I cannot seem to wrap my mind around a certain thing.

For a website, I created a button that randomizes the destination. This means that a person clicking the button is randomly redirected to a different page. I was wondering how I can alternate between destinations so that someone first clicking the button is going to page one and the next person to page two.

This is the script for randomizing at the moment:

```
<script>
   var randomlinks=new Array()

   randomlinks[0]="juice.html"
   randomlinks[1]="no-juice.html"

   function randomlink(){
   window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
   }
</script>
```

In the script I call this by using

```
<form method="post">
   <p><input class = "button button1" type="button" name="B1" value="Start Test >>" onclick="randomlink()"></p>
</form>
```

I would appreciate some help! Thanks in advance (:

Comment: what do you by mean "the next person"? if you mean the next website visitor then that cannot be done on the front end alone. you'll need to write your logic on the server side.

Comment: if your code runs locally, and you mean the next click on the same client then that can be achieved

Comment: Try alternating the array in a server database. In that way the visitors are detected for the links change. Until then it is shuffling within their own browsers.

Comment: The next person is indeed the next visitor

Answer (score 0):

Working client-side only, you can't share the code between two separated clients (A and B, for example), so you can't force two distinct visitors to ping-pong between your links.

Comment: whatever code we use on the client side will not affect the next person/visitor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you think there is there another way to achieve this then? I can’t use random, because I need to have an equal amount of visitors for A and B.

Comment: Doing client-side solo is not possible. You can setup a simple server-side Node.JS application which talks to the front-end and decide which link serve, based on some condition. I can't give you some code snippets since it's out of the scope of this question, but you can find tons of resources to learn on Google.